# Equal Width Menu Items Generated Dynamically and Browser Compliant

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I am creating a navigation menu where each menu item needs to be equal width, out of total width of 970px. The amount of items will be dynamic (Sometimes 6, 7 or 5). The main issue I am having is that my current method of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Navigation Tab Width Calculation
    var nCnt = $("#nav > li").length;
    var navConstraint = 970 - (nCnt - 1);
    var nWidth = navConstraint / nCnt;

    //// Sets Distributed Width of items
    $("#nav > li > a").css({ "width": nWidth + "px" });

    //// Sets Width of ul in submenus
    $("#nav ul").css({ "width": nWidth + "px" });

    //// Sets Width of li in submenus
    $("#nav ul li").css({ "width": nWidth + "px" });

    //// Sets Width of a tags in submenus width an adjustment for padding
    $("#nav ul li a").css({ "width": nWidth - 10 + "px" });

    /// Width Fixes for first and last nav elements
    $("#nav > li:first").css({ "margin-left": "0px" });

    //// Fixes the last item to fit the stock image width, by browser if necessary
    var lastOffset = 1;

    $("#nav > li a:last").width(nWidth - lastOffset);

    //// Adds Vertical Centering for Menu Items
    $("#nav").children("li").each(function () {
            var nh = ($(this).find("a").find(".navText").height());

            if (nh < 20) {
                    $(this).find(".navTextPadder").height(11);
            }
            else {
                    $(this).find(".navTextPadder").height(7);
            }

    });
```

The problem I run into is that  IE browsers don't handle the widths as well, not sure if they can't handle decimal widths or not but it is shorter than in FF which is pretty damn exact. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code?

Comment: No matter how you do this, the end result will not always add back up to exactly 970 pixels.  You'll have to settle for something a few pixels off depending on the number of menu items.  Or you'll have to figure out what's left over and create a div that visually makes up for the difference.  If you remove the fractional part of the result and stick with whole numbers, you'll at least be consistent from browser to browser.

Comment: I need to do exactly what the OP requested, but when I attempt to create a living example, I'm obviously missing something: http://jsfiddle.net/fUK9W/1/

Answer (score -1):

Use Math.floor or something to round your numbers.

Another way to do it is to use a good old table :

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Rounding the calculated pixel values to whole numbers is a very good idea.  Using `<table>` elements for layouts is just sloppy programming.

Comment: Using something simple, supported by all browsers, that _used_ to be the norm and that pad really well something that is lacking in CSS is a bad idea? You are being too much of a purist. Fixing a layout issue in JavaScript is the bad idea.

Comment: Yes... using tables for layouts is sloppy and recommending that people use them for layouts is irresponsible.  You also misunderstand the OP's question.  If he's "dynamically" changing the number of items in his menu, using tables won't make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Sloppy, maybe, in a good way (remember *KISS*?). Irresponsible, no. And you don't seems to know how table work, **they will adjust** "dynamically". I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBcAw/) so you can see it. I do not *generally* recommend the use of table for layout.

Comment: @Kraz:  Obviously, tables will adjust dynamically to width... geesh!  Like I said already, using tables or DIVs makes no difference to his particular issue.

Comment: @Kraz:  Also, the OP wants each menu item to be the same width but he did not say they'd each have the same exact content.  Your JSFiddle does not take that into account.  [See this one.](http://jsfiddle.net/FBcAw/2/)  **BTW:  You are really adding & removing COLUMNS from your JSFiddle, not rows!  lol**

Comment: Ops, dumb error x2 :P (and my suggestion become width=(100/nbCol)% instead of width=(970/nbCol)px...)(no no, I won't suggest using a **spacer.gif**)

Comment: @Kraz:  Thank-you... now we're back where we all started, calculating the widths.  Table cells or divs, pixels or percentages -> same problem.